# Beetroot doesn't grow

Tags: seedlings, beetroot

I tried to grow beets in Central Europe, where it is a common plant. It's the third year that my little seedlings, which germinate very nicely, stop growing. Their leaves turn red, then turn yellow and stop growing. They don't die. I have to be doing something wrong, but I can't figure it out. I changed the variety and seeds, I changed the soil, I sowed both directly and transplanted, I tried multi-sowing and nothing helps. I would be very grateful for any advice.

[image]

Comment: Do the plants receive more than 6 hours of sun?

Comment: Do other plants grow OK in your soil? Just wondering if there's anything toxic that might be poisoning them? Are they getting enough water?

Comment: Yes, there is a lot of sun there but I always try to make some shade for the plants. For example plants on the photo grow under the garlic. I wouldn't say they suffer from the sun.

Comment: Other plants grow just fine. They get enough water. Thank you.